# How to remove sign-in restriction from Google Form programmatically?

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am creating Google Forms programmatically with a Google Script project.

DriveApp is used to grant *view* access to *anyone with a link*.

```
var form = FormApp.create("Test form");
var formFile = DriveApp.getFileById(form.getId());
formFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
```

However the Form still requires "anyone" to sign-in and it's restricted to my G Suite domain users. I've tried to find how to disable this but I don't know how the feature is even called in Google Scripts.

See the attached image with a checked box:

[image]

Note: I can disable the sign-in requirement manually. But Forms are delivered to respondents automatically and there's no time to do this manual step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had to do this, so I'm not sure if it's what you need, but have you tried using the setRequireLogin(requireLogin) method when creating your forms?

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setRequireLogin(Boolean)

Comment: That's it! I can't believe I didn't find this from the documentation myself. Thanks @DavidJCC!